# Moving node labels around in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
% -------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% triangle
\node (a) [draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, minimum size=6cm,
            label=corner 1:$a$, label=corner 2:$b$, label=corner 3:$c$] at (0, 0) {}; 
% dotted axis
\foreach \x in {1, 2, 3}{
  \draw [darkgray, dashed, shorten <=-0.4cm, shorten >=-0.4cm](a.center) -- (a.side \x);
  \draw [darkgray, dashed, shorten <=-0.37cm, shorten >=-0.37cm](a.center) -- (a.corner \x);
}
% indicating sense of rotation
\draw [x=0.07cm, y=0.3cm, -stealth, rotate=90] (a.corner 1) + (0.2, -0.15cm) arc (-150:150:1);
\draw [x=0.07cm, y=0.3cm, -stealth, rotate=-150] (a.corner 2) + (0.2, -0.15cm) arc (-150:150:1);
\draw [x=0.07cm, y=0.3cm, -stealth, rotate=-30] (a.corner 3) + (0.2, -0.15cm) arc (-150:150:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the picture:

[image]

How can I space out the three corner labels so that they're not on top of the other lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels are just nodes so they understand all the usual keys like `anchor`, `shift` and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
% -------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% triangle
\node (a) [draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, minimum size=6cm,
            label={[anchor=south west,yshift=1mm]corner 1:$a$}, 
            label={[yshift=-1mm]corner 2:$b$}, 
            label={[yshift=-1mm]corner 3:$c$}] at (0, 0) {}; 
% dotted axis
\foreach \x in {1, 2, 3}{
  \draw [darkgray, dashed, shorten <=-0.4cm, shorten >=-0.4cm](a.center) -- (a.side \x);
  \draw [darkgray, dashed, shorten <=-0.37cm, shorten >=-0.37cm](a.center) -- (a.corner \x);
}
% indicating sense of rotation
\draw [x=0.07cm, y=0.3cm, -stealth, rotate=90] (a.corner 1) + (0.2, -0.15cm) arc (-150:150:1);
\draw [x=0.07cm, y=0.3cm, -stealth, rotate=-150] (a.corner 2) + (0.2, -0.15cm) arc (-150:150:1);
\draw [x=0.07cm, y=0.3cm, -stealth, rotate=-30] (a.corner 3) + (0.2, -0.15cm) arc (-150:150:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]